# Is there a simple way to duplicate an Android activity in the same project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I have an Activity that, with a few modifications, would work extremely well as another part of the app I'm working on. I was wondering if it's possible to easily duplicate an Activity in Android Studio without needing to manually copy all of its dependencies (activity_my.xml for example).

Comment: can you give us few more details in your question, as the question is too broad right now

Comment: Can't you just create a new activity and call it something else, and then copy-paste in the old activity? You would then just need to do the work of renaming any relevant parts to match your new activity name. That at least is close to what I've always done when there was a fragment class for example than I needed to duplicate quickly

Comment: What's to copy other than code and the xml? :D maybe 2 xmls!

Answer (score 3):

To get it right: You have code you want to reuse in another Activity.

Now, the way I would do this would not be to copy the reused code (because if you want to modify it, you have to modify both copies, which is tedious work).

I'd create a base-activity, that has the functionality that both of your Activities need. This functionality would have to be slightly abstracted so that both activites could use this functionality by extending this BaseActivity and use it for their individual purposes.

If you post some code (the part of code both of your activities should have), I could update my answer to show you how that would look like in your case.

Comment: Good approach , maybe you will check `IOSched 15' BaseActivity` : [BaseActivity](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java) In this Activity there is `NavigationDrawer` here. And you can use it extending this when creating new Activity.